# Issue splitting ListBox line back into 3 values

Tags: c#, listbox, split

I had three values (Name, Course and Average) which were assigned to 3 arrays. I had to combine them and put them in a listbox. Now, I need to be able to select the same line and break it back up into the 3 variables.

My listbox output looks like this:

```
Lastname, firstname     SEC360    93.5
```

I tried to do a split with space, but that breaks up my lastname and firstname, which need to be one combined variable with the comma included (I need to check it against the array in which it is placed). I cannot do substring either, because I do not have a set value. Any ideas?

EDIT:
I am sorry everyone. Im a inexperienced programmer (to say the least) and new to this site.

This is where I loaded the arrays:

```
studentNamesAr[studentCount] = studentNameTxtBox.Text;
courseAr[studentCount] = courseNumTxtBox.Text;
gradesAr[studentCount, 0] = Convert.ToInt32(grade1TxtBox.Text);
gradesAr[studentCount, 1] = Convert.ToInt32(grade2TxtBox.Text);
gradesAr[studentCount, 2] = Convert.ToInt32(grade3TxtBox.Text);
gradesAr[studentCount, 3] = Convert.ToInt32(grade4TxtBox.Text);
```

This is where I load the arrays to the listbox:

```
for (int i = 0; i != studentCount; i++)
        {
            studentAvg = ((gradesAr[i, 0] + gradesAr[i, 1] + gradesAr[i, 2] + gradesAr[i, 3]) / 4);
            studentListBox.Items.Add(string.Format("{0, -20} {1, 20} {2, 20:F1}", studentNamesAr[i], courseAr[i], studentAvg));
        }
```

Yes this is Windows Forms.

Data is not lost in arrays. When the program runs I should have maybe 5 entries. I need to split them back up so that when I select one from the listbox (to delete it), I will find the values in the 3 arrays and delete them, and then shift the remaining array values up.

Comment: 1.)  Read [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). 2.) Any particular reason you're combining them to a `ListBox`? (Hint: Do 1 first, and 2 will be answered.)

Comment: It would be easier to just the the listbox index and work with the original values, but it sounds like you don't have the original arrays any more when the selection is made?

Comment: When you combine them, why not combine like this? Lastname|firstname|SEC360 93.5 Then you can do a split on the pipe character.

Comment: @TyrionLannister Are you saying the question isn't readable enough to provide an answer?

Comment: @Brian Salta, you could input another character to split on however, he wants the name part to stay in the format "Lastname,Firstname" so it would be like Lastname, firstname|SEC360 93.5

Comment: @MrLister: I'm saying it needs code, it needs to know what code he's tried, and we need context into what's happening after he combines them.  If the arrays are moving out of scope and are lost, that's one thing.  But if they are still intact, then why not use those?

Comment: WPF? WinForms? ASP.NET? Code you attempted?

Comment: I am so sorry. Yes this is Windows Forms. I have edited and added a lot more information. Please let me know if you need any more information from me!

Comment: 1.) Is this homework?  2.) Do you have to use `Array`s?  Can, and have you considered, using `List`s?

Comment: Yes, it is as assignment. We have to use Arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you preserve the order of your items in the listbox, the SelectedIndex of the listbox *should* match up with the indices from your original arrays. So once you have that, you can go about shifting your arrays up (which is pretty tedious).

For the record, there are much better constructs to use to approach this problem, but I'm assuming the stipulation of using arrays is part of a homework assignment. :)

Comment: How would you go about shifting up the arrays?

Comment: Imma let him figure that out. Don't want to take all the fun out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could hold the value separated by some other delimiter in the .Tag property.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to replace the ", " (notice the space after the ',') with something else (like ";") then use the split method with space as the parameter.

```
string s = "Lastname, firstname SEC360 93.5";
string[] result = s.Replace(", ", ";").Split(' ');
```

then you may change back the result[0] by replacing ";" with ", "